# Change table value in database with dropdown option

Tags: jsf

I'm using primefaces in my project and my question is the following:

I have, for example, a table Table1 with a field "Active" that is a bit.

I want Table1 to change that field from 0 to 1 when I select the "active" option from the dropdown and from 1 to 0 when I select the "de-activate" option. This changes should only be done when I hit the "Update" button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Mahendran: you can use mcve in square brackets like [ mcve ] (but without the spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only gonna have those two options in your dropdown you can make it like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.object.field}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Active" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="De-Activate" itemValue="0" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

By doing that, the parameter "field" in your object will get value one if the "Active" option is selected, same for the other option. After that you click your update button, which I suppose is calling the update method of your object.

Answer (score 1):

You need a

```
    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{yourBean.onCheckboxSelect}" />
```

Bean Method:

```
 public void onCheckboxSelect(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
 // here change the value. Through the event you can get the checkbox state.
}
```

Then add an ActionListener to the Button which uses the chained value to change it in your database.

For further Information you should  see PrimeFaces Showcase -> http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/.
And for a more detailed answer you **should add some code**.